# How to Drag the listbox Item near the SelectedItem Alone

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

I want to drag the listbox selected item. Dragging function is working fine. My requirement is dragging should not happen while drag started from any other location in listbox. I have did like this, but that is not working. Please anyone suggest me to achieve this,

```
        private bool IsDragging { get; set; }
        private Point _startPoint { get; set; }        

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {                            
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseMove;

        }

        private void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && !IsDragging)
            {

                Point position = e.GetPosition(null);                      

                if (Math.Abs(position.X - _startPoint.X) <= SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance &&
                    Math.Abs(position.Y - _startPoint.Y) <= SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
                {
                    StartDrag(sender);
                }
            }
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
        }



        private void StartDrag(object sender)
        {

            IsDragging = true;

            if (sender is ListBox)
            {
                var listBox = (sender as ListBox);
                if (listBox != null)
                {
                    var selectedMember = listBox.SelectedItem;
                    if (selectedMember != null)
                    {
                        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, selectedMember, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                    }
                }
            }

            IsDragging = false;

        }
```

[Please refer the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC9kl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this, By using `System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, point)` it gives the current element under the mouse. I think it will help you.

```
private bool IsDrag { get; set; }              

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {            
            this.AssociatedObject.Drop += AssociatedObject_Drop;            
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseMove;

        }

        private void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {                                  
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {               
                if(IsDrag)
                {
                    StartDrag(sender);
                }
            }
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsDrag = false;    

            if(sender is ListBox)
            {
                Point initialPoint = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
                var histPoint = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(sender as ListBox, initialPoint);

                if (histPoint.VisualHit != null)
                {
                    if (histPoint.VisualHit is TextBlock || histPoint.VisualHit is Border)
                    {
                        IsDrag = true;
                    }
                }
            }            
        }                   

        private void StartDrag(object sender)
        {            
            if (sender is ListBox)
            {
                var listBox = (sender as ListBox);
                if (listBox != null)
                {
                    var selectedMember = listBox.SelectedItem;
                    if (selectedMember != null)
                    {
                        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, selectedMember, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
```